# Extremely high RAM usage without it adding up

Tags: windows-10, memory

Things arent adding up and its very frustrating. I have 16GB of RAM that I ran under memtest and it came clean, Fedora showed only 1GB ram usage.

> [image: Task Manager]

Comment: Fedora? You're under MS-Windows?!

Comment: Please add a `!` in front of the image reference so it becomes inline.

Comment: Also your screenshot shows about 6Gb used already so already 50% of the RAM right there. I would think there are many more processes running. And if you're running Fedora in a VPS, it could be using quite a bit of RAM to make it work. But I don't see that in your screenshot.

Comment: What do you think should be adding up to what?

Comment: @AlexisWilke If someone is a new user they cannot properly embed an image in a post. They can only upload the image linked as you saw perviously. This is done to discourage spamming and general abuse. What needs to happen is someone with more rep, your or me for example, needs to edit the post to properly set the image as an inline image.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager's memory performance view.

Comment: There quite a few questions on superuser about the processes tab and the shown memory. The simple answer is that this tab is not designed to view your memory usage.

Comment: Your image does unfortunately not work. // Please [add new information to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1737938/edit). You can edit your question at any time.

Comment: [Task Manager's memory performance view.](https://imgur.com/a/hNVyxfG) Fixed it @DanielB